# Regex - Detecting type of data with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with some regex, and I'm in need of help.

I'm actually as interested in understanding "how-to" as to have something working.

My app need to read a file and store element depending on type.
I need to detect **type** of element
I'm struggling because I need to differentiate STRING and STRINGLIST.

STRING are usually delimited by >< in my apps , so
`>C175012331000400200<` matches my regex : `^>\\w+<$`

And the extracted text is C175012331000400200.

That's good... but :

**First problem:**
But, when it comes to STRINGLIST :

```
>"ProfileId:ATA GRAPHICS.GREXCHANGE<|>","ProfileEd:2.6","SourceCreated b<|>y IsoDraw 7.3,CGM Filter 10.22.50.<|>06","Date:20161207","ColourClass:c<|>olour"<
```

The STRINGS delimiters ( >< ) are there , and the extracted string is :

```
 "ProfileId:ATA GRAPHICS.GREXCHANGE","ProfileEd:2.6","SourceCreated by IsoDraw 7.3,CGM Filter 10.22.50.06","Date:20161207","ColourClass:colour"
```

And so, I know this is a STRINGLIST because there are "," separating the strings.

I was not able to create a regex detecting that so I fallback on detecting the **<|>** sequence.
If it can help, the length between the >< delimiters are max *35* characters.
Ideally, I'd like to detect the `","` in the delimiters but all things I test were wrong.

Then came the **big problem** :

I figure out some of my input file were binary encoded .
So the new representation of data for STRING are now :

```
>00C00100700500000100600200000100000<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  C1750162010|>0000001000000000000002<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  00100002
```

Where in fact, I need to store all values, but the human readable one are stored in the UTF16 subpart.

And so, the STRINGLIST data binary-encoded are too hard for me :

```
>00C00r00e00a00t00e00d00 00b00y00 00<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  Created by|>I00s00o00D00r00a00w00 00700.00300,<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  IsoDraw 7.3,|>00C00G00M00 00F00i00l00t00e00r00 00<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  CGM Filter|>100000.00200200.00500000.000006<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  10.22.50.06
```

Where the extracted STRING ( that allow to detect it is a STRINGLIST ) is

```
  Created by  IsoDraw 7.3,  CGM Filter 10.22.50.06
```

*Please note that in this case , the >< delimiter are now for rawdata and not "meaning"
Please also note that in this case, the double-quote defining the STRING in the STRINGLIST are now gone. SO in this case, the STRINGLIST is identified thanks -*only*- to the **,** character.*

---

TL/DR :

I need to detect type of element:

```
>C175012331000400200<
```

Extracted text: `C175012331000400200`
Type: **STRING**
Regex : `^>\\w+<$`
( Double \ because of Java string interpretation )

---

```
>"ProfileId:ATA GRAPHICS.GREXCHANGE<|>","ProfileEd:2.6","SourceCreated b<|>y IsoDraw
7.3,CGM Filter 10.22.50.<|>06","Date:20161207","ColourClass:c<|>olour"<
```

Extracted text:

```
*"ProfileId:ATA GRAPHICS.GREXCHANGE","ProfileEd:2.6","SourceCreated by IsoDraw 7.3,CGM Filter
10.22.50.06","Date:20161207","ColourClass:colour"*
```

Type: **STRINGLIST**
REGEX : `.+<\\|+>` 
( Double \ because of Java string interpretation )

---

```
>00C00100700500000100600200000100000<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  C1750162010|>0000001000000000000002<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  00100002
```

Extracted text: `C175016201000100002`
Type: **STRING**
REGEX : None yet

---

```
>00C00r00e00a00t00e00d00 00b00y00 00<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  Created by|>I00s00o00D00r00a00w00
00700.00300,<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  IsoDraw 7.3,|>00C00G00M00 00F00i00l00t00e00r00 00<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  CGM Filter|>100000.00200200.00500000.000006<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  10.22.50.06
```

Extracted text: `Created by  IsoDraw 7.3,  CGM Filter 10.22.50.06`
Type: **STRINGLIST**
REGEX : None yet

---

Thanks in advance !!!!

EDIT 1 : Due to the response, first thank you guys, second the first question should be "Is regex a good way to do that" ... My apps detect others types of data so I associate 1 regex with a type. 
I checked the norm of the imput files and I finally figure out that "," is only for non encoded STRINGLIST so the regex `^(.*)(?=\",\")(.*)$` is fine for that kind of element.

Annex question : is there a way to regroup regex group in order to parse them ?
Like : getting all the text after UTF16 then work on it to detect , character ...

EDIT 2: After thinking about it , I decide to go along the following rules for the encoded data ( I can have  multiples detection regex for one type).
And the regex and the corresponding type are stored in a LinkedHashMap , so I know the order.
For the ENCODEDLISTSTRING , I'll try to detect first value "UTF16" and try to see if there is a , before the next > character so `(UTF16->(.+),(.+)>)` should do the trick.
If the regex does not match I'll look for UTF16 for the ENCODEDSTRING with `(UTF16->(.+)>?)`

Comment: Does "extracted text" mean "expected output"?

Comment: I think you are trying to parse some text to get your desired output, regex is not inteded for parsing complex texts. Yes you can use regex to help you parsing, but just parts and do the logic some other way.

Comment: @Edwin [*Regular expressions provide a declarative language to match patterns within strings. They are commonly used for string validation, parsing, and transformation.*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: @revo you can use for simple parsing, but be my guest to parse example 2 and 3 from here using just one regex and then reuse it for other texts

Comment: @revo : The extracted text is the string that has a meaning. It is the real value I need to work with

Comment: @revo The fact that you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should* do it all the time. Regular expressions have their place, but then: when **you** are unable to define the regex that solves your problem, then maybe writing a real, distinct parser is the **better** solution. What does it help to have some guru give you a regex that you don't understand, but have to maintain over time. Do you go back to SO each time you need to enhance that regex? Thus my ground rule is: when I have to turn to SO to explain the regex I need to me, then I better not use that regex.

Comment: @GhostCat : agreed , but not knowing how to do something should forbid you to do it ? In that case, when do you learn ?. IMHO, this is a challenge and I'm clearly not good enough to succeed it. But I still want to try

Comment: @user1808484 That is not what I am saying ;-) ... the point is that different aspects come together that require balancing. A complex regex that you never have to look at later on is maybe fine. But when that regex sits in the middle of everything you do and becomes a constant source of trouble, then maybe a different solution would well, be less of a problem.

Comment: The first thing you have to do is formally define the syntax of your files by any means. Based on the syntax you can decide if regex is applicable and if yes, the translation will be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

So here are the regexes:

```
^(>)([\\w|\\d]*)(<)$
```

for your

```
>C175012331000400200<
```

explanation: take all the text containing digits and letters which is wrapped in `> <`

```
(?s)(.)+(<|>)*
```

for text (this is not completely tested)

```
>"ProfileId:ATA GRAPHICS.GREXCHANGE<|>","ProfileEd:2.6","SourceCreated b<|>y IsoDraw 
7.3,CGM Filter 10.22.50.<|>06","Date:20161207","ColourClass:c<|>olour"<
```

explanation: `(?s)` should check on all lines, even if there is a newline.
`(.)+(<|>)*` get groups of text and `<|>` and then you should use just the groups that you are interested in.

```
(?s)((.*UTF16->)([\\s|\\.|\\w|\\d]+)(|)?)*
```

to match:

```
>00C00r00e00a00t00e00d00 00b00y00 00<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  Created by|>I00s00o00D00r00a00w00
00700.00300,<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  IsoDraw 7.3,|>00C00G00M00 00F00i00l00t00e00r00 00<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  CGM Filter|>100000.00200200.00500000.000006<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  10.22.50.06
```

and

```
>00C00100700500000100600200000100000<|hex->  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  C1750162010|>0000001000000000000002<|hex->   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^|UTF16->  00100002
```

explanation: `(?s)` converts all new lines to `.` then you have two delimiters `UTF16->` and `|` where in between is your desired text.

You need now just to use the right groups from the regex and you are fine.

Comment: Thank you! 
My goal is more to detect type than work with captured group as once the good type detected, I have a dedicated object per type that is able to extract the data from the raw.
In your exemple, for the encoded data, do you think it is possible to differentiate the two ?

Comment: differentiate what exactly? I don't follow you ...and what do you mean by type?

Comment: My goal is to matchs rawdata coming from the input and detect the data type. For exemple, the rawdata is >C175012331000400200< and so according to the norm this is a String because of the >< delimiters.

But when the input is binary encoded , this is not working but I still need to detect if the rawdata is a String of a StringList ( If there is a , character in the UTF16 section, this means the rawdata is a StringList ).
The responsability of the method I'm working on is to send back a type of data, not to manipulate the data itself.
Am I clearer ?

Comment: I guess you should know the data and how to interpret it, how can I even possible do that for you? and btw. from all your "extracted texts" looks like you have only Strings. And I guess this is already out of the scope of the question.